# Ruby valid license plate regex

Tags: ruby, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to write a function in RUBY that will determine if a given string is a valid license plate. A valid license plate has the following format: 3 capital letters, followed by a dash, followed by 4 numbers. EX: `HES-2098`.

I have written the following function but need some help for pattern matching.

```
def liscence()
  plate = "HES-2098"
  plateNo = plate.upcase
 if(plate.length == 8)

   if(plate == plateNo)

    if(/\A-Z\A-Z\A-Z\-\d{4}/.match(plate))
       puts "valid"
     else
       puts "invalid"
     end


   else
     puts "First 3 letter must be uppercase"
   end

 else
   puts "Only 8 char long"

 end

end

liscence()
```

Comment: `if(/\A[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}\z/.match(plate))`

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem

Comment: I posted the pattern with the explanations and demos.

Comment: [Rubular](http://rubular.com) is your friend. See http://rubular.com/r/9Kn4fk96ci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex did not work because `\A` matches a string start position that can only be one in a string (and you have three). To match an uppercase ASCII letter, you may use a `[A-Z]` character class.

You can use

```
if /\A[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}\z/ =~ plate
```

See the [regex](http://rubular.com/r/jxmstfDLej) and [Ruby](https://ideone.com/qPzkNG) demos.

**Pattern details**:

- `\A` - start of string (not line, as with `^`) anchor
- `[A-Z]{3}` - exactly 3 (since the limiting quantifier `{n}` is used) uppercase ASCII letters (from the `[A-Z]` range in a character class)
- `-` - a literal hyphen (not necessary to escape it outside the character class)
- `[0-9]{4}` - exactly 4 ASCII digits
- `\z` - the very end of the string anchor (not `$` that matches the end of the line)

Answer (score 2):

```
plate[/\A[A-Z]{3}-\d{4}\z/] ? 'valid' : 'invalid'
```

Comment: afaik `plate =~ /regex/` is ~30% faster than `plate[/regex/]`

Comment: @smefju it can’t be just `N% faster` because it should strongly depend on the string length, plus it can’t anyhow differ when there is no match. For _plates_ thinking about this is called “premature optimization.” There should be used a variant, that is easier to read and in my opinion the one I introduced reads better. The latter is of course disputable :)